# What was Natsu dreaming about in Lucy's room?

Tags: fairy-tail

I don't think I'm the only one who is wondering this; if I am, correct me. What was Natsu dreaming about when he woke up in Lucy's room? He woke up scared - was there a special reason or was it just to make us laugh?

Edit: This occurs in the Episode 76 of the First Season of Fairy Tail.

Comment: IIRC. It was the time he suddenly woke up alone and found Igneel had gone? Can you drop in the Chapter/Episode?

Comment: It was in Episode 76.

Comment: Upon rewatching, I see I didn't recall that incident. Added the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered it wrong, Lol. The dream is about Lisanna. Infact it is shown clearly in the first minute before the opening.

*We see a young Natsu searching for Lisanna in the forest, he trips and falls. He hears a girl scream, shouts Lisanna and wakes up.* So clearly the nightmare was about the "death" of Lisanna.

This is infact an anime only scene. [FT Wikia: Episode 76](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_76)

> The anime adds a scene in which Natsu wakes up from a bad dream about Lisanna, with Lucy questioning him about it and yelling at him because he is in her bed and forced her to sleep on the floor.